# Unable to use FactoryGirl traits in constructor method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I and trying to make use of traits and are getting an error when I try to declare one in my specs

Rails version is 4.0.2
FactoryGirl 4.3.0

```
FactoryGirl.define do

      factory :user do

          name "pete"

          trait :admin do
              admin true
          end

      end

end
```

//in the spec

```
user = create(:user, :admin)
```

//fails with

NoMethodError:
      undefined method 'admin=' for #

Can anyone see where I went wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: has the `User` model the field `admin`?

Comment: How do you use `admin`? `user.admin = true` or `user.admin(true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first make sure that the `User` model has the field *`admin`*? Then if you don't need the reuse the attributes as it is allowed by `trait` property, use factories as it was described in the [manual](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
   factory :user do
      name "pete"
      factory :admin do
         admin true
      end
   end
end
```

and create the factorie as:

```
user = create :user
admin = create :admin
```

Use traits if you have to create cross-used model properties, like for example, *`male/female`*, along with *`admin/non-admin`*.